Optimization on $L^2$ norm
I am given vectors: $a_1,\ldots, a_m\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and I am given the following minimization question:
$$\sum_{j=1}^m \| x-a_j\|_2^2$$ given the constraint that: $\|x\|_2^2=1$. Denote by $\hat{a}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m a_j$.
I want to show that if $\hat{a}\ne 0$, then there are unique minimum and unique maximum for this problem.
So I built here a Lagrangian: $F(x,\lambda)=\sum_{j=1}^m \|x\|_2^2+\|a_j\|_2^2-2x\cdot a_j +\lambda (\|x\|_2^2-1)$.
So after taking $\partial /\partial x F(x,\lambda)=0$, I get that: $x^*=\frac{1}{m+\lambda}\sum_{j=1}^ma_j$.
Now I need to use the constraint, i.e. : $\frac{1}{(m+\lambda)^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^m a_i\cdot a_j=1$.
But I don't see how to choose lambda appropariately and showing which one is the max and which one is the min.
Any help?
Thanks in advance!

$\frac{1}{(m+\lambda)^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^m a_i\cdot a_j=1 \implies m+\lambda = \pm\|\sum_i a_i\|_2 \implies x^{*} =  \pm\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\|\sum_i a_i\|_2}$.

how do you know that $a_i\cdot a_j = 0 $ for $i\ne j$? it's not given that they are orthogonal to each other.

Why I need that? It’s sum of vectors, and then norm squared. Actually I would not even bother expanding it as double summations of inner product. Just to inherit your expression, and start from there

But $\sum_{i,j=1}^m a_i\cdot a_j = \sum_{i=1}^m |a_i|^2+2\sum_{i=1}^m a_i\cdot a_j$ which is not necessarily $\sum_{i=1}^m |a_i|^2$.

It’s $|\sum|^2$

Yes you are correct. Didn't notice this. Thanks!
